# Microsoft Teams meeting participants list report through API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to get all participants list through API

doc link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Through this documentation, an API to get a list of participants' records.

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/%7Bid%7D)

**From where I can get this {id}.**

Comment: Sujeet, were you able to get id?

Comment: @KiranKumar No...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the id of a callRecord:

1. Subscribe to [change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) to the /communications/callRecords endpoint.
2. Use the callChainId property of a call. The call record is available only after the associated call is completed.

Comment: I tried the second option but not didn't get the {id}.
If you have done this then please give me any resource link.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please try the api to [create call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)? After the call is succesfully created you will get the callChainId. You could use that for your further requests.